# My function can't output string array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I think the answer to this is pretty obvious, but it's friday so my brain isn't functioning entirely.

I'm working in an asp.net mvc application where I get the id of a selected row. Every time I click a row the id of that row is send to my controller.

What I want to do is output the id just as regular plain text. 
This isn't too hard, I use this code:

```
public string GetInformation(int id)
        {
           return id.toString();
        }
```

But the user can select multiple rows at once, what happens now is that the id just changes from the first selected row to the second one.

What I want is both the id's to be returned, separated by a comma.

This is what I tried:

```
public string[] GetInformation(int id)
        {
            List<string> oud = new List<string>();
            oud.Add(id.ToString());
            return oud.ToArray();
        }
```

But then it just shows `System.String[]` as output.

Comment: Your `GetInformation` only takes a single `id`, where does the second one come from?

Comment: @RonBeyer when you click a row again, the GetInformation function is called again

Comment: So you want to print the string-array and get the actual values instead of `System.String[]`? Try `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", yourArray));` (the `", "` is your separator between values)

Comment: @KevinTinnemans Then the list should be outside of the function, otherwise you aren't adding anything, the list is created again each time the function is called. Then, inside the function you want to call `return string.Join(',', oud);` Just keep in mind you need a method to clear the list out at some point.

Comment: The list will be created on each request to the browser. You might want to add some sort of state to your list. Possibly, dare I say it... session? How about passing in an array of ids managed on the client to your GetInformation method? Seems pointless though, you already have the information you need on the client anyway. Ps. Has no one read the fact he's using .net mvc? Stop with the Console write lines!

Comment: Yeah, I changed that @RonBeyer, the list is now initialized outside of the function, but your string.Join doesn't do anything; I still only see one string, the same as how my code was in the first place

Comment: You may need to store the selected items somewhere that doesn't get reset each time. The easiest place would be a cookie or session variable, or you can use a database or memory cache store.

Comment: Do you use  'Console.Writeline(GetInformation(1));' or 'Console.Writeline(GetInformation(1)[0]);' Not sure how you call/want to use it but the [0] can make a lot of difference

Comment: @Kyra I'm using asp.net mvc, I can't "Console.Writeline"

Comment: I mean how you are reading it, example was easier with console. But do you read the entire list, or do you read the values of the list. I think the entire list, based on the return you get

Comment: @RonBeyer to be brutally honest with you, I don't know anything about cookies and memory cache stores. Session variables are php right? And a database isn't really an option

Comment: ASP supports sessions. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Every time you call `GetInformation(int id)`, you create a new instance of `List<string>`, add one item and then return the List as an array. This way your List will always just have 1 item so I don't really understand why you're using a List in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to prefix this by saying that I think using sessions for state is generally a bad idea. However, it's an easy way to show state management and retaining the list between requests.

Update your function to this:

```
        public string[] GetInformation(int id)
        {
            var list = Session["oud"] as List<string>;

            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<string>();
                Session["oud"] = list;
            }

            list.Add(id.ToString());

            return list.ToArray();
        }
```

Each time you call this method it will get the list from session (user state management). If the list returned from session is null (it's not actually there) we create a new list of strings and add it to the session.

To test this I put the following in an index action of an MVC controller before return View(). When I refresh the page I can see the random id being appended to the list. The same will apply if you make a call from the client.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        GetInformation(r.Next(1, 10));
```

Hope this helps!

---

## Update

### Iterating over an array in razor view and printing each item

In your razor view, if you have added this array to your model as `MyIds`, you could use the following:

```
@foreach (var id in Model.MyIds)
{
    <p>@Html.Raw(id)</p>
}
```

---

## Update 2

I'm going to make this very easy for you:

```
        public string GetInformation(int id)
        {
            var list = Session["oud"] as List<string>;

            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<string>();
                Session["oud"] = list;
            }

            list.Add(id.ToString());

            return string.Join(", ", list);
        }
```

The function now returns a comma separated list of ids that you have passed through.

Comment: You need to show us where you are actually printing out the result so we can fix it for you. Remember that you can't just print out the array, you have to iterate over it and print each item in the array.

Comment: I think that's the problem, the only thing I do is return the variable

Comment: Then where do you see the System.String[]?

Comment: on the bottom of my grid, the grid is where the user can select the rows

Comment: @KevinTinnemans Added Razor example for iterating over an array and printing out the values

Comment: @KevinTinnemans show us the code that is printing the string "System.String[]". Hopefully the update to my answer will help.

Comment: @KevenTinnemans the code of how you put it in the grid is necessary for the correct answer. Now it's just guessing

Comment: How I put what into the grid @Kyra?

Comment: The value of the getInformation(int id), Update 2 is a good one, and will solve your issue

Comment: Updated answer so that GetInformation returns a string (you can just write this out) that has the IDs comma separated. No iterating or anything for you. When your original GetInformatoin function returns string[] it made what you wanted very unclear.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenGourley, I really appreciate your efforts, I know it must be frustrating to help someone like me, but i'm just trying to get better everyday :)

Comment: It's no problem. You essentially had 2 problems: retaining state between requests and printing out the string. I'm not sure if you got as far to realise the problem with the state, but you should always show the code thats causing the problem, in this case how you were attempting to print the string. That's why you got answers about writing to the console etc,and that's why I included razor code; the most common when using mvc. I've no idea if you're using razor or aspx

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that you should keep the views concerned with the presentation of your data. The controller should return the data, in this case an array or list, but it should be the concern of the view to interpret this array as a comma delimited string and print it out. Essentially you now can't use this function to get the array in its raw form, meaning that you can't iterate over it and display it in paragraph tags for example.

Answer (score 2):

> But then it just shows System.String[] as output.

Well, you're not showing us how you actually *output* anything.  But presumably you're getting a value:

```
var output = GetInformation(input);
```

and then trying to write `output` directly as a `string`.  However, `string[]` is an array and doesn't have a default string representation.  All objects in .NET which don't have a `.ToString()` implementation inherit their implementation from `System.Object`, which defaults to outputting the type name.

Instead of outputting the object itself, which is *semantically* something like this:

```
Write(output)
```

(again, *semantically*, since we don't know how you're actually outputting it, so consider this pseudo-code)

Loop over it for your output:

```
foreach (var value in output)
    Write(value)
```

You'll have to handle formatting (new lines, delimiters, etc.) for however you want to display the values as a UI concern.  But the point, basically, is that you need to loop over your values and output them individually rather than as one big array.

There are shortcuts which will loop over it for you, if you'd like.  For example:

```
Write(string.Join(",", output))
```

That would "join" all of the strings in `output` for you, using `","` as a delimiter.

---

**Edit:** Another problem that you seem to be experiencing is that your method only ever returns a *new* list of exactly one object:

```
public string[] GetInformation(int id)
{
    List<string> oud = new List<string>();
    oud.Add(id.ToString());
    return oud.ToArray();
}
```

This method shouldn't really have the responsibility of maintaining the list.  This is because the method itself is stateless, all it really does is convert an integer value to a string.  (Which you don't really need a method for, but whatever.)  Consuming code should maintain state.

So keep the method as-is:

```
public string GetInformation(int id)
{
    return id.toString();
}
```

And have the consuming code maintain the collection of values.  Something like this:

```
var output = GetInformation(input);
myOutputs.Add(output);
```

Where is `myOutputs` defined?  Well, where that state is maintained depends on a lot of things.  This is a web application, so *state* can be an interesting thing.  There are many places to maintain it:

- Within the consuming method as a method-level variable
- Within the consuming class as a class-level value
- In session state
- In a database
- etc.

The overall flow of the logic and the application is going to govern this.  For example, if a single instance of the class is maintaining the entire lifetime of this process then you would put it in a class-level value.  However, if the value needs to persist across different page requests then you might want to put it in Session State instead.  You have a number of options for where to maintain this collection of strings.

Comment: You may want to address the fact that the list will never contain more than one element how its written, the OP is asking how to add another item to the list on each method call. Because the list is new'd up each time, there is no list of values returned, is only one, no matter what.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Interesting, I didn't notice that.  I'll update the answer with some suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
public string[] GetInformation(int id)
{
    List<string> oud = new List<string>();
    oud.Add(id.ToString());
    return oud.ToArray();
} 

var myResult = GetInformation(1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myResult);
```

---

It's more nice to return unformatted data and format it when needed.

```
public int[] GetInformation(int id)
{
    List<int> oud = new List<int>();
    oud.Add(id);
    return oud.ToArray();
} 

var myResult = GetInformation(1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myResult);
```

Comment: This is invalid code, you have statements outside of a method that are required to be inside a method. This is also an ASP application so Console.WriteXXX isn't going to do much (should see it in the debug console, but not anywhere else).

Comment: I just updated it, it's just for showing HOW to solve this.

Comment: Its not any different though, the list will only ever contain a single element, no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: Try add more items? `oud.Add(id);`